# SQL Server 2008 XML Attribute search is case sensitive

Tags: sql, xml

I store user preferences in an XML column which looks like this:

```
<tags>
    <user> 
        <tag name="AB"/>
    </user>
</tags/>
```

When I use the query below,

```
select * 
from company 
where CAST(tags.query('tags/user/tag[fn:contains(@name,"Ab")]') as varchar(2000) ) <> ''
```

it does not return any results, the attribute value is in different case then one in the xml column.

Any ideas on making the search by attribute name case insensitive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008 you can make use of the lower-case and upper-case functions like so:

```
select * from company where CAST(tags.query('tags/user/tag[fn:contains(lower-case(@name),"ab")]') as varchar(2000) ) <>''
```

see:

[New XQuery functions introduced in SQL Server 2008: upper-case() and lower-case()](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2009/05/27/new-xquery-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2008-upper-case-and-lower-case.aspx)

[lower-case Function (XQuery) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645589.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdavies. it is working but the query is taking long time to execute. Is there a better way to do what I am trying?

Comment: As far as I am concerned there is nothing wrong with your query (but I am by no means an expert). Is your company table very large? Does it take a lot longer for other queries or simple selects from the table? Maybe you could take a look at indexing the tags column: [Indexes on XML Data Type Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx).

Comment: @FullMetal5000 - Try to use exist instead of cast and query. `where tags.exist('tags/user/tag[fn:contains(lower-case(@name),"ab")]') = 1`